# Geode SecurityManager implementation

Tags: gemfire, geode

I am currently lost on the requirement to implement a SecurityManager interface in Java / Geode per [Implementing Authentication](https://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/geode/managing/security/implementing_authentication.html).

Is there standard implementation that I can point to in `gemfire.properties` to handle the `security-username` and `security-password` properties?

I got as far as taking the [ExampleSecurityManager](https://github.com/apache/geode/blob/develop/geode-core/src/main/java/org/apache/geode/examples/security/ExampleSecurityManager.java) java class and saving it to the Geode bin directory, and then trying to point the `security-manager` property to it.

`security-manager=org.apache.geode.security.examples.ExampleSecurityManager`

If I run Geode out of the box and do exactly that then the locator fails to start with `org.apache.geode.security.GemFireSecurityException: Instance could not be obtained, java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.geode.security.examples.ExampleSecurityManager`

A crazy question. THANKS for your comment.

Comment: I think you have a dyslexic class name :) Try `org.apache.geode.examples.security.ExampleSecurityManager`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@JensD thanks once again. I [requested](https://github.com/apache/geode/pull/861) to update the [Javadoc](https://geode.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/geode/examples/security/ExampleSecurityManager.html) but the [Custom Security Manager](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/GEODE/Using+Custom+SecurityManager) page has it the right way around!

It should be `org.apache.geode.examples.security.ExampleSecurityManager`